# How big is a culture bomb?

Tags: civilization-5

Ghandi (the cheeky bastard) just culture bombed my border near his capital, securing several important resources.  However, I wasn't watching at the time and so am unsure how many culture bombs he used or how many tiles he grabbed.

I'd like to reclaim some of my resources, but I also want to use my bombs as effectively as possible.  How many tiles can a culture bomb capture?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A culture bomb will take all the tiles surrounding the tile bombed:

[image: diagram]

In other words, if you bomb the green tile, all the red ones would be taken.  However, the bombed tile must be either 
**owned by you** or **neutral and adjacent to a tile owned by you**.

Comment: True, but keep in mind that you can't trigger the bomb in someone else's territory.  So the green space has to belong to you or nobody, and as a result in practice you will generally end up only capturing 3 or 4 tiles.

Comment: To be more accurate: all the red ones *plus* the green one will be taken. This means the maximum tiles that can be captured from one bomb are 6 (since you can only activate the bomb in tiles inside of, or adjacent to, your territory).

Comment: Isn't there some time-limit involved as well? I.e., you can't culture bomb consecutively, or something?

Comment: @Raven correct, on "normal" settings I believe the limit is 10 turns between each usage.

Answer (score 9):

According to [the official Civ 5 wiki](http://wiki.2kgames.com/civ5/index.php/Great_artist):

> A Great Artist can "Culture Bomb" any tile inside or adjacent to your territory. That tile and all six surrounding it immediately become your territory.